# Printing array elements in CGI table in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, xhtml, cgi

I'm trying to print an array elements in a table like this:

```
+------+-----+-------+------+
| One  | Two | Three | Four | Header
+---------------------------+
| 1    | 2   | 3     | 4    | Row 1
+---------------------------+
| 5    | 6   | 7     | 8    | Row 2
+---------------------------+
```

I used this code:

```
my @array = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','8');
print $q->table({-border=>1},
      $q->Tr($q->th(['One','Two','Three','Four'])),
      $q->Tr($q->td(\@array))
);
```

But I end up with this:

```
+------+-----+-------+------+---------+
| One  | Two | Three | Four |         |
+---------------------------+---------+
| 1    | 2   | 3     | 4    | 5 6 7 8 |
+------+-----+-------+------+---------+
```

So what shall I do different to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ':standard';

my $q     = CGI->new;
my @array = 1 .. 8;
my @td;

while ( my @elems = splice @array, 0, 4 ) {
    push @td, $q->td( \@elems );
}

print $q->table(
    { -border => 1 },
    $q->Tr( $q->th( [ 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four' ] ) ),
    $q->Tr( \@td )
);
```

Output (with manually-inserted newlines):

```
<table border="1">
<tr><th>One</th> <th>Two</th> <th>Three</th> <th>Four</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td> <td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td> <td>6</td> <td>7</td> <td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a good answer already, but I just wanted to point out that using the HTML-generation functions from CGI.pm went out of fashion over fifteen years ago. You will find your application is far easier to maintain and improve if you switch to using [a good templating system](https://metacpan.org/release/Template-Toolkit).